# How use SYS_REFCURSUR in select for update in pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to select multiple rows and also update all selected rows. so this goal i wrote this query. but when execute it throw exception.

I wrote this query in a producer like bellow.

```
PROCEDURE get_rows(
   a_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
   a_id IN VARCHAR,
   a_count IN NUMBER);
```

exception detail:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence

`a_cursor` is SYS_REFCURSOR

```
OPEN a_cursor FOR
  SELECT mytable.VID
  FROM   mytable
  WHERE  ROWNUM <= COUNT FOR UPDATE;

loop 
  FETCH a_cursor INTO a_id;
  if a_cursor %notfound then
    cnumber := 9999;
  else
    UPDATE mytable SET
    ...
    WHERE  VID = a_vid;
    COMMIT;
  end if;
end loop;
```

Comment: The problem is not your ref cursor. The problem is the `COMMIT` inside the loop in conjunction with your `FOR UPDATE` cursor.  Committing causes all the locks held by the `FOR UPDATE` to disappear.  To protect you, Oracle closes the cursor and your next attempt to FETCH give you the `ORA-1002`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `sys_refcursor` cannot be used in `update` statement. You can use an explicit cursor as shown below. Use this way:

```
    DECLARE
    cursor a_cursor is
      SELECT mytable.VID
      FROM   mytable
      WHERE  ROWNUM <= COUNT FOR UPDATE;

    a_id number;
    begin
    OPEN a_cursor;
    loop     
      FETCH a_cursor INTO a_id;          
      exit when a_cursor%notfound; 

        UPDATE mytable SET
        ...
        WHERE  VID = a_vid;                   
    end loop;
    COMMIT;
   close a_cursor;
 end;
```

Edit:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE get_rows(
                                   a_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
                                   a_id IN VARCHAR,
                                   a_count IN NUMBER)
IS                                   
cursor a_cur is
  SELECT mytable.VID
  FROM   mytable
  WHERE  ROWNUM <= a_COUNT ;

a_id NUMBER;
cnumber number;
BEGIN 
OPEN a_cur;

 LOOP
  FETCH a_cur INTO a_id; 

  IF a_cur%notfound THEN
   cnumber := 9999;
  End if;

  exit when a_cursor%notfound; 

    UPDATE mytable SET
     ...
    WHERE  VID = a_vid;
  END loop;
  COMMIT;    
  CLOSE a_cur;

  Open a_cursor for select * from mytable;

end ;
```

Comment: @ali see edited answer. It shows how you can take the out paramater as `SYS_REFCURSOR`.

Comment: @ali you helped yourself i just showed you the path .:-)

Answer (score 2):

If you are not doing any other processing in the loop, you can use a `MERGE` statement instead of a cursor:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d7f26/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable ( vid, columna ) AS
SELECT 1, 'a' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'a' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'a' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'a' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'a' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'a' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
MERGE INTO mytable dst
USING (
  SELECT VID /* or ROWID AS rid */
  FROM   mytable
  WHERE  ROWNUM <= 3
) src
ON ( src.VID = dst.VID /* or src.RID = dst.ROWID */ )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET
    columna = 'b'
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d7f26/3/1)**:

```
| VID | COLUMNA |
|-----|---------|
|   1 |       b |
|   2 |       b |
|   3 |       b |
|   4 |       a |
|   5 |       a |
|   6 |       a |
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I want to use `a_cursor` in my application.