# oracle - how to create an object type for an already existing table

Tags: oracle, object, plsql, types

We have a requirement where we have to pass the table name to a pl/SQL object at the runtime.

Below is the example

```
create or replace FUNCTION ABC
(P_TABLE VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS 
C_REFERENCE SYS_REFCURSOR;
V_TABLE VARCHAR2(50):=P_TABLE;
V_C_REF v_table%rowtype;
BEGIN
OPEN C_REFERENCE FOR 'SELECT * FROM '||V_TABLE||;
LOOP
FETCH C_REFERENCE INTO V_C_REF;
EXIT WHEN C_REFERENCE%NOTFOUND;
/*some processing*/
END LOOP;
return(1);
END;
```

The above code will give me an error. Is there any workaround for it? Table name can vary and different tables will have different structures.

Comment: Use explicit `cursor` in place of `sys_refcursor`. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50581147/how-use-sys-refcursur-in-select-for-update-in-pl-sql/50581274#50581274

Answer (score 0):

The rowtype declaration, has to be static (if it's not, the compiler can't tell if the fields referenced from it are valid).

Possible solutions are:

- Put a comma separated list of variables in the INTO clause:

  ```
  FETCH C_REFERENCE INTO var1, var2, var3;
  ```
- Create your own record

  ```
   TYPE  V_C_REF IS RECORD ( col1 VARCHAR2(20), col2 VARCHAR2(25) );
  ```
- Use a table with the expected estructure

  ```
  vc_ref table1%ROWTYPE;
  ```
- write a PL/SQL function to query `dba_tab_columns` and get the column size and type definition.